# Receiving java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index error while invoking database function

Tags: java, sql, function

I am trying to invoke a database function using callable statement. The signature of the Stored Procedure is given below;

```
 function DUMMY_FUNCTION (PARAM1          in    Number
                               ,PARAM2    in    Number
                               ,PARAM3 in    varchar2
                               ,PARAM4          in    Number
                               ,PARAM5           in    Date
                               ,PARAM6          in    Number 
                               ,PARAM7         out    varchar2
                               ,PARAM8           out    varchar2)
```

return varchar2;

and the JAVA code for invoking is as below:

```html
//Load SQl Binaries
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class InvokeProcedure {

public static String callProcedure(int PARAM1,int PARAM2,String PARAM3,int PARAM4,String PARAM5,int PARAM6) throws Exception {
    //Defining Parameters
 String result = new String();
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    String outParam = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        conn = getDBConnection();

        String proc3Function =
            "{? = call P1SCHEMA.DUMMY_PACKAGE.DUMMY_FUNCTION(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        cs = conn.prepareCall(proc3Function);
        java.sql.Date param5date = new java.sql.Date( sdf.parse(PARAM5).getTime() );
        //DefiningInput Parameters
        cs.setInt(1, PARAM1);
        cs.setInt(2, PARAM2);
        cs.setString(3, PARAM3);
        cs.setInt(4, PARAM4);
        cs.setDate(5, param5date);
        cs.setInt(6, PARAM6);
        //Defining Output Parameters
        cs.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(9, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        //Execute Statement
        cs.execute();
        //Capture Output
        outParam = cs.getString(8);
        String I = new String(outParam);
        //Set Resultant Array
        result = I.toString() + "###" + cs.getString(7) + "###" + cs.getString(8) + "###" + cs.getString(9);
        //Check the Reason Code Returned from Stored Procedure
        if (outParam == "S") 
        {
            //Roll back Transaction
         conn.rollback();
        }
        else
        {
            //Commit Transaction
         conn.commit();
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally 
    {
        if (cs != null)
        {
            //Close Connection
         cs.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) 
        {
         //Close Connection
         conn.close();
        }
    }
    // Return Array to Client
    return result;
}

public static Connection getDBConnection() throws Exception {
   String driver = "oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource";
   String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1539:DEV";
   String username = "user";
   String password = "password";

   Class.forName(driver);
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
   return conn;
   }


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

 InvokeProcedure INP = new InvokeProcedure();
String Args = INP.callProcedure(1,2,"A",3,"2016-01-23",4);

System.out.println(Args);

}
}
```

While running the java program I am getting the below exception, not sure where i am doing wrong

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:122)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:379)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1568)
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like your function have only 2 out parameters, but you are registering 3

Comment: Hi Stan, i have the return varchar2 also at the end, while building the schema , i am getting three parameters.

Comment: Sorry, missed it since it was out of snippet. I suppose you need to register output parameter first since you have statement '? = ...' so it will be cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR); and then other parameters without last one of course

Comment: Great Thanks .. Silly Mistake :) Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has 8 parameters, but the call has only six `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`:

```
"{? = call P1SCHEMA.DUMMY_PACKAGE.DUMMY_FUNCTION(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
```

Use:

```
"{? = call P1SCHEMA.DUMMY_PACKAGE.DUMMY_FUNCTION(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
```

An then - the positional parameters `?` are numbered from left to right.
:

- `{? =` - this is the first parameter, it's index is 1, 
  use `cs.registerOutParameter( 1, java.sql.Types.SomeType)`
- `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` there are consecutively 2,3,4,....8,9 parameters

Use:

```
cs.setInt(2, PARAM1);
cs.setInt(3, PARAM2);
cs.setString(4, PARAM3);
...
```

Two last parameters with indexes: 8,9 are OUT parameter - register them using:

```
cs.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(9, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, missed it since it was out of snippet. I suppose you need to register output parameter first since you have statement '? = ...' so it will be cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR); and then other parameters without last one of course by Stan